# How to get the array content when value is object?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, which contains different data types. Those are int and object. The array is as follows.

```
Array ( 
  [isHR] => 1 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [0] => MyQuota Object ( 
      [year:private] => 2011 
      [leaveId:private] => L001 
      [employeeId:private] => 
      [NoOfDays:private] => 7.00 
      [leaveName:private] => Casual Leave 
      [Message:private] => 
    ) 
    [1] => MyQuota Object ( 
      [year:private] => 2011 
      [leaveId:private] => LTY002 
      [employeeId:private] => 
      [NoOfDays:private] => 55.00 
      [leaveName:private] => Priviledged Leave
      [Message:private] => 
    ) 
  ) 
  [Length] => 8 
)
```

Here I need to get and set array attribute called "NoOfDays:private". How can I get this?

Comment: its a private property of the object so you cant access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add getters and setters:

```
class MyQuota
{
    private $year;
    private $leaveId;
    private $employeeId;
    private $NoOfDays;
    private $leaveMessage;
    private $Message;

    /* more code */

    public function getNoOfDays()
    {
        return $this->NoOfDays;
    }

    public function setNoOfDays($noOfDays)
    {
        $this->NoOfDays = $noOfDays;
    }

    /* more getters and setters */

}
```

And, with your array, use it like this:

```
$days = $array[0][1]->getNoOfDays();
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the most easiest and straightforward ways, please refer to this page. 
[1] http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Answer (score 1):

You may not have an access to private properties of an object. either make them public or define getter and setter methods.

to access the public properties:

```
echo $arr[1][0]->NoOfDays
```